# Axios put events Google Calendar api with React

Tags: reactjs, axios, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I want to insert an event using axios post request.
This is the code:

```
async function inserisciTurni() {
axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarioselezionato}/events`, {
  calendarId: `${calendarioselezionato}`,
  resource: evento,
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },

}).then((result) => { console.log(result) })


var evento = {
"summary": "Titolo prova evento",
"description": "prova evento",
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2022-08-28T09:00:00-07:00",
},
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2022-08-28T17:00:00-07:00",
}  };
```

But I receive this error:

[image: IMAGE ERROR 401]

Comment: Please include your error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, your request body is correct. But, I thought that it is required to modify the method for requesting. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async function inserisciTurni() {
  var accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  var calendarioselezionato = "###"; // Please set your calendar ID.

  var evento = {
    "summary": "Titolo prova evento",
    "description": "prova evento",
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2022-08-28T09:00:00-07:00",
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2022-08-28T17:00:00-07:00",
    }
  };
  var res = await axios.post(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarioselezionato}/events`,
    JSON.stringify(evento),
    {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, "Content-Type": "application/json"}}
  );
  console.log(res.data);
}
```

#### Note:

- When I tested this modified script, I could confirm that an event could be created in my Calendar.

#### References:

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: @Gabbrobob Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.